# Método void retorna itens para a lista, mas quando tento usar essa lista, ela está vazia!

Tags: android-studio, método, android-adapter

```
 listaPedidoComprador.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listaPedidoComprador.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterPedidoComprador = new AdapterPedidoComprador(itensCarrinho2);
    System.out.println(String.format("quantidade que está no itensCarrinho pro adapter:  %d ", itensCarrinho.size()));
    listaPedidoComprador.setAdapter(adapterPedidoComprador);
    adapterPedidoComprador.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterPedidoComprador.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAddClick(int position) {
            ItemPedido itemPedido = itensCarrinho2.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(CompradorPedidos.this, itemPedido.getNomeProduto(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    recuperarItemPedidoJamilton();

    System.out.println(String.format("pedidos recuperados: %d", produtos.size()));
    System.out.println(String.format("quantidade que está no carrinho:  %d nesse exato momento fora do método", itensCarrinho.size()));
    System.out.println(String.format("quantidade que está no carrinho2:  %d nesse exato momento fora do método", itensCarrinho2.size()));
    System.out.println("eae bb");

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //recuperarItemPedidoJamilton();
}

private void recuperarItemPedidoJamilton() {
    DatabaseReference produtoref = firebaseRef
            .child("pedidos_usuario")
            .child(idUsuarioLogado);

    produtoref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                pedidoRecuperado = dataSnapshot.getValue(Pedido.class);
                itensCarrinho2 = pedidoRecuperado.getItens();
                adapterPedidoComprador.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println(String.format("quantidade que está no carrinhoJamilton:  %d nesse exato momento", itensCarrinho2.size()));
            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(CompradorPedidos.this, "Seu carrinho está vazio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Error
        }

    });
    System.out.println(String.format("quantidade que está no carrinhoJamiltonfora:  %d nesse exato momento", itensCarrinho.size()));

}
```

Como podem ver, eu estou tentando colocar essa lista no adapter, mas não da certo pois essa lista aparentemente está vazia. Não entendo o que está ocorrendo, já que coloquei um println dentro do método e ele está retornando que há tem itens dentro da lista!!

Já tentei deixar o itensCarrinho2 (lista de  que estou tentando preencher) estático, porém não consigo trabalhar bem assim pois há casos em que é necessário apagar a lista, pois é um carrinho de compras, e ao confirmar ou retirar um item do carrinho, não consegue ser retirado da lista que está estática... eu suponho...

Comment: Olá. Por favor, detalhe melhor a situação que está acontecendo. Eu entendi que você adicionou uma lista ao adapter que inicialmente deve estar vazia, e não está adicionando o item novo nela antes de chamar o `notifyDataSetChanged()` do adapter.

Comment: Estou tentando colocar pro meu adapter a lista itensCarrinho2, como pode ver no código, eu chamo um método pra preencher essa lista (recuperarItemPedidoJamilton();) e eu sei que essa lista está sendo preenchida dentro do método por conta do println que coloquei lá dentro (ele mostra que tem itens na lista usando o itensCarrinho2.size.), mas no momento que chamo pro adapter, ela está vazia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendi agora.

Bom, entenda que `itensCarrinhos2` é uma referência para um objeto lista, não o próprio objeto. Você passou essa referência para o adapter e este não espera que ela seja mudada, apenas que mude o conteúdo do objeto em si (ou seja, o conteúdo da lista).

Portanto quando você faz `itensCarrinho2 = pedidoRecuperado.getItens();` você aponta essa variável para outro objeto, no caso para o que está sendo retornado por `getItens()`, só que quando chama `notifyDataSetChanged()` o adapter não sabe disso e verifica o objeto apontado pela referência passada a ele anteriormente, que não mudou.

Lembre-se que em Java os argumentos são sempre passados "por valor", ou seja, é feita uma cópia do argumento que está sendo passado, no caso a referência para a lista, e o adapter passa a guardar internamente uma cópia dessa referência. Enquanto as duas estiverem apontando para o mesmo objeto ótimo, tudo funciona, mas você mudou isso no seu código quando fez `itensCarrinho2` apontar para outro objeto.

A solução portanto é das duas uma, ou alterar somente o conteúdo da lista através da própria referência que o adapter já conhece:

```
itensCarrinho2.clear();
itensCarrinho2.addAll(pedidoRecuperado.getItens());
adapterPedidoComprador.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

...ou então procurar um método na classe/interface-base do adapter que permita atualizar a referência que foi passada ao adapter, um `setDataSet()` da vida ou algo assim, não lembro se tem um.

Comment: *"Lembre-se que em Java os argumentos são sempre passados "por referência""*  olha, que eu me lembro os valores em java são sempre *"pass-by-value"*, pode confirmar isso, só pra não deixar dúvidas? tem até essa pergunta afimando isso no SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @RicardoPontual Perdão, eu sempre confundo os dois termos. Você está certo, é por valor mesmo, já corrigi. Por isso particularmente gosto de falar "por cópia".

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!!!!! <3 deu certo aqui :') muito obrigado @Piozevan, de verdade mesmo !!!!

Comment: @JoãoVitor Faça o [tour]

Comment: @RicardoPontual Se bem que falando "por cópia", se não souber que a referência está só apontando para o objeto e não é o próprio objeto irá continuar ambíguo do mesmo jeito.

Comment: sim, isso pode confundir. Eu prefiro como é dito em C#, "by value" e "by reference", me parece que fica mais claro pelo menos pra entender